# AngularJS: Style individual form fields when ng-model is changed in texfield

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I've asked a similar question a couple of times already, and I'm afraid I've not been specific enough.

Suppose in my controller I have an object of type person called "guy" that looks like this:

```
{"ID"        : "1234",
 "firstName" : "Bob",
 "lastName"  : "Michael",
 "phone"     : "555-555-5555",
}
```

(Note: The object that I'm working with is *similar* to this -- but it's much larger)

Now suppose I had a webpage with a form and a search box.  The form has a field for each attribute in the object, like this:

```
<label for="inputFirstName"> First Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="inputFirstName" ng-model = "person.firstName">

<label for="inputLastName"> Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="inputFirstName" ng-model = "person.lastName">

<label for="inputPhone"> Phone Number: </label>
<input type="text" id="inputPhone" ng-model="person.phone">
```

When an "ID" number is searched on the page, the form is populated with the corresponding data in the object.  There is also an "import" button on the page.  When this is pressed, a person object is brought in to the controller that is identical to guy except firstName is now "Dan" and phone is now "111-111-1111".  The variable "guy" is set equal to this newly imported object, effectively changing or "updating" the object with these changes.  These changes immediately show up in the form, as expected.

What I would like to be able to do is to highlight the fields that have been changed once the import button has been pressed.  However, I've been unsuccessful in my attempts.  I tried doing something like this:

```
 <label for="inputFirstName" 
        ng-class = "{ 'newCSS' : !!hasChanged }"> 
    First Name: 
 </label>
 <input type="text" 
        id=inputFirstName" 
        ng-model="person.firstName" 
        ng-change = "hasChanged = true">
```

But this only works when I type a change in the text box manually -- not when I click the import button and the actual object itself is changed.  When I asked this question before, someone suggested that I use $watch like this:

Controller
    function demoCtrl ($scope) {

```
$scope.$watch('myModel', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
       $scope.hasChanged = true;
    }
 }, true);

$scope.changeMyModel = function () {
   $scope.myModel = 'wonderful';
 };

}
```

HTML

```
  <label for="stuff" ng-class="{ 'newCSS' : !!hasChanged }">Stuff</label>
  <input type="text" id="stuff" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="hasChanged = true">

  <button ng-click="changeMyModel()">change model</button>

</div>
```

But this doesn't work either.  For one thing, the $watch doesn't seem to register when I press the button, so I've not gotten it to run successfully yet.  For another, I'm not sure how this would work for what I'm trying to do.  Assuming all of my labels/inputs are set up this way, wouldn't all of the fields be highlighted, even if only one is changed since hasChanged will be toggled to true if one attribute of the new object is different than the old object?

Bleh..I'm just a little confused.  How would I go about implementing this successfully? (i.e. When a change is imported, the fields that have been changed are highlighted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past to achieve this I have used Angular.copy to create a copy of the object in scope and then compared original and current.

Something like this

**Controller**

```
$scope.originalPerson = $angular.copy($scope.person);
```

**View**

```
<label for="inputFirstName" 
       ng-class="originalPerson.firstName == person.firstName ? oldCss:newCss">
        First Name:
</label>
```

Comment: Did this help you or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Lol, I'm sorry to have gotten back to you so late.  Yes, this did help me!